# Mootools delete event not working after Drag + droppable event

Tags: mootools, mootools-events, mootools-sortable

I need to fix a few things here:

1. The delete button does not work after the drop event. The delete only works on items not in the dropzone. Not sure what is wrong here.
   also, it would be better to add the delete button to each dropped item instead of cloning it.
2. I need to be able sort the dropped items. 
   sortable is not included in the current demo below.

HTML:

```
    <div id="items">
    <div class="item"><span>Item 111111</span>
    <span class="delete"><button>Delete Line</button></span>
    </div>

    <div class="item"><span>Item 222222</span>
    <span class="delete"><button>Delete Line</button></span>
    </div>

    <div class="item"><span>Item 333333</span>
    <span class="delete"><button>Delete Line</button></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="" id="cart">
    <div class="info">Drag Items Here</div>
</div>


<div class=""><span>test delete works here but not after a drag event</span>
    <span class="delete"><button>Delete Line</button></span>
    </div>
```

Here is the DomReady event:

```
   $$('.item').addEvent('mousedown', function (event) {
    event.stop();

    // `this` refers to the element with the .item class
    var item = this;

    var clone = item.clone().setStyles(item.getCoordinates()).setStyles({
        opacity: 0.7,
        position: 'absolute'
    }).inject(document.body);

    var drag = new Drag.Move(clone, {

        droppables: $('cart'),

        onDrop: function (dragging, cart) {

            dragging.destroy();
            item.removeClass('item');
            item.addClass('item_dz');

            if (cart != null) {
                item.clone().inject(cart);
                cart.highlight('#4679BD', '#FFF');
                item.removeClass('item_dz');
                item.addClass('item');
            }
        },
        onEnter: function (dragging, cart) {
            cart.tween('background-color', '#FFF04F');
        },
        onLeave: function (dragging, cart) {
            cart.tween('background-color', '#FFF');
        },
        onCancel: function (dragging) {
            dragging.destroy();
        }
    });
    drag.start(event);
});


$$('.delete').addEvents({
    click: function () {
        this.getParent().destroy();
        this.destroy();
    },
    mouseover: function () {
        this.tween('opacity', '1');
        this.getPrevious(['.item_dz']).fade(0.3);
        this.getPrevious(['.item_dz']).tween('background-color', '#fff', '#f00');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        this.tween('opacity', '0.5');
        this.getPrevious(['.item_dz']).fade(1);
        this.getPrevious(['.item_dz']).tween('background-color', '#f00', '#fff');
    }
});
```

[Current Jsfiddle code demo](http://jsfiddle.net/htscraig/pk9UP/1/)

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things you are missing.

**The first is** that this code starting here

```
$$('.item').addEvent('mousedown', function (event){
    event.stop();
```

is preventing this one to fire (since `.delete` is descendent of `.item`):

```
$$('.delete').addEvents({
    click: function () {
        this.getParent().destroy();
        this.destroy();
    },
```

This can be fixed by adding this line between the two I posted, to ignore the drag if the click was in the `button`

```
if (event.target == this.getParent().getElement('.delete button')) return;
```

**The second problem is** that you need to delegate the click event on the dropped element. You could do this like:

```
window.addEvent('click:relay(.delete)', function (){
    this.getParent().destroy();
    this.destroy();
})
```

So changing that you get this: http://jsfiddle.net/m6xDt/

About the sorting part I didn't get what you wanted. If you explain that better I will try to help with that also.

To make the cart sortable:

Start a new sortable class and then add each new item to it inside the onDrop event:

```
var mySortables = new Sortables('', {
    clone: true,
    opacity: 0.7
});
```

and then inside the onDrop:

```
mySortables.addLists(cart);
```

#### http://jsfiddle.net/m6xDt/

Comment: The items that are collected in the drop zone need be made sortable. Using Mootools sortables. This would make it easy to rearrange the line items.

Comment: The last dropped item on the list doesn't sort for some reason.

Updated http://jsfiddle.net/htscraig/pk9UP/6/

Comment: @CraigMartin I think this is related with a bug that has been fixed in newer versions. We actually released V1.5 yesterday! So maybe time to upgrade? :) Anyway, for your problem a small `setTimeout`seems to fix it. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pk9UP/8/

Comment: Having trouble with this: http://jsfiddle.net/htscraig/vhkGD/5/
It works ok in Firefox and Safari but not has stopped working in Chrome.
The content of textarea is erased when dropped but only in Chrome. Your thoughts?

Comment: @CraigMartin can you tell me what I should do to make the error happen? I will look at it tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Just open http://jsfiddle.net/htscraig/vhkGD/5/ in both chrome and firefox and try to drag/drop from the questions to the edit area on the right. you will see that the text in the textarea box is erased when dropping in chrome only. works in firefox and other browsers. Maybe some kind of change with Chrome Version 43 is affecting it.

Comment: This version may be easier for you to see what is going on in chrome.  
updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/htscraig/czkuc3nb/

Comment: Ok, I'm using v42 in this computer. Will check later on a newer Chrome. Cheers

Comment: @CraigMartin tried Chrome 44, seems to be a bug with Chrome, not MooTools. Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/dfyf1k7p/2/ - will investigate also.